# Integrating Tab Navigator with our app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

We have a React Native mobile application that that uses stack navigator. We have

- config.js screen for our stack navigator
- separate pages for screens
- index.js to bring it all together

Could someone please help me figure out how to integrate a tab navigator into our app? Something like a ribbon at the bottom of our HomeScreen. Examples would be greatly appreciated. I have browsed all the internet; the examples online don't show up on the screen.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share what you have done so far. Otherwise your question might be downvoted for being too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one will help you [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)

Comment: This is a great library.  Was a beast transitioning my app to it, but it's been TOTALLY worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below some react native tab plugins and select best suitable according to your requirements:
https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-tabs